# How to change code so that pictures be in "main-block", instead of a js-code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change this javascript code - http://jsbin.com/ciduhegukinu/2/edit 
How to change this code so that pictures be in "main-block", instead of a js-code. And then already to bring them in the slides array in javascript.

And that the structure of all the page was following:

**I want:**

```
------------------------
Big picture (100% width)
-----------------------
menu ||| galery
-----------------------
```

**Instead of (I have now):**

```
.................
galery (100 width 100 height)
................
```

**I want (don't work):**

```
var div = document.getElementById("main-block");
    var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var slides = Array.prototype.forEach.call(images,function (el) {
        slides.push(el.getAttribute("src"));
    });
    Slider.init({
        images : slides
    })
```

**Instead of (it is work):**

```
Slider.init(document.body,{ 
        images : [
            "http://cdn.trinixy.ru/pics3/20080515/vodopadi_18.jpg",
            "http://i.redigo.ru/4fb0dd2a4e202.jpg",
            "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dN_zBi_BLio/Uli2RStTf2I/AAAAAAAAIH4/EpGnraB6qu8/s1600/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B02.jpg",
            "http://www.uznayvse.ru/images/stories/uzn_1384119271.jpg",
            "http://i.redigo.ru/4fb0dd2a4e202.jpg",
        ]
          });
```

Also surely there has to be a scrolling down in the browser if the photo is much. In galleries has to be on 3 photos at line.

**All my code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <div width="300px" id="content">
      <img src="images/top.gif" width="100%" height="300px">
   <table border="3px">
  <tr>
<td>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<div id="menu_foto">
<li><a href=""></a></li><br>
<li><a href=""></a></li><br>
<li><a href=""></a></li><br>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
</td>
<td>
<div id="main-block">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/1.jpg">
    <img src="images/fotogalery/2.jpg"><br>
    <img src="images/fotogalery/3.jpg">
    <img src="images/fotogalery/4.jpg"><br>
    <img src="images/fotogalery/5.jpg">
    <img src="images/fotogalery/6.jpg"><br>
    <img src="images/fotogalery/7.jpg">
    <img src="images/fotogalery/8.jpg"><br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>



<style>
        html,body{

            margin:0px;
        }
        #cap {

            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            display:flex;
            z-index : 99999;
            position:fixed;         
        }
        figure {
            padding:0px;
            margin:100px auto;
            width:800px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        img {
                        height: 450px;
            width:550px;
            border:5px solid white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin:auto;
        }
        ul {
            width:810px;
            list-style:none;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        li {
            width:810px;
            position:absolute;
            opacity:0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        li:first-child{
            opacity:1;
        }
        .previewSlide{
            width:250px;
            height:250px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            margin:10px;
        }
</style>





<script>
    var Slider = {
        Collection : [],
        currentSlide : 0,
        Box : {
            showBox : function (n) {
                if(!this.element) return;
                this.element.style.display = "flex";
                document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

                var slides = this.element.getElementsByTagName("li");
                slides.item(n).style.opacity = 1;
                Slider.currentSlide = n;
            },
            closeBox : function (n) {
                if(!this.element) return;
                this.element.style.display = "none";
                document.body.style.overflow = "auto";

                var slides = this.element.getElementsByTagName("li");
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides,function (el) {
                    el.style.opacity = 0;
                })
            }
        },
        Prevew : {
            element : {},
            init : function (p) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.id = "previewSlides";
                div.style.position = "fixed";

                for(var i in Slider.Collection) {
                    var figure = document.createElement("figure");
                    figure.setAttribute("class","previewSlide");

                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = Slider.Collection[i];
                    img.onclick = (function (i) {
                        var i = i;
                        return function (e) {
                            Slider.Box.showBox(i);
                        }
                    })(i);

                    figure.appendChild(img);
                    div.appendChild(figure);

                    this.element = div;
                }
                p.appendChild(div)
            }
        }
    }

    Slider.init = function (p,options) {
        var opt = options || {};
        this.Collection = opt.images;
        var self = this;


        (function (p) {
            var cap = document.createElement("div");
            cap.id = "cap";

            var figure = document.createElement("figure");
            figure.id = "slideWrapper";

            var ul = document.createElement("ul");
            ul.setAttribute("class","slideList");
            ul.style.left = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < self.Collection.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var img = document.createElement("img")
                img.src = self.Collection[i];

                li.appendChild(img);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.class = "slide";
            img.src = self.Collection[0] || "";

            p.appendChild(cap);
            cap.appendChild(figure);
            figure.appendChild(ul);

            self.Box.element = cap;
            self.Box.closeBox();

            self.Prevew.init(p);
        })(p);
    }

    Slider.changeSlide = function (dir) {
        var slides = this.Box.element.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var l = this.Collection.length;
        slides.item(this.currentSlide).style.opacity = 0;
        (dir) ? this.currentSlide ++ : this.currentSlide--;

        if(this.currentSlide == l) this.currentSlide = 0;
        if(this.currentSlide < 0) this.currentSlide = l-1;

        slides.item(this.currentSlide).style.opacity = 1;

    };


var div = document.getElementById("main-block");
var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");

var slides = Array.prototype.forEach.call(images,function (el) {
    slides.push(el.getAttribute("src"));
});

Slider.init(document.body,{ 
        images : slides
          });


    Slider.Box.element.onclick = function (e) {
        if(e.target.tagName != "IMG") Slider.Box.closeBox();
        else { 
            if(e.clientX > (e.target.offsetWidth + e.target.style.width/2) ) Slider.changeSlide(false);
            else Slider.changeSlide(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've removed your question's [tag:java] tag as the question appears to have nothing to do with programming in Java (please do correct me if I'm wrong). I ask that you strive to be very careful with your question tags, as correct and informative tags are the best way of attracting the right experts to your problem, while the opposite is true if your tags are incorrect. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. That JsBin has nothing in common with the HTML provided. Also I don't get it when you said `in "main-block", instead of a js-code` could you explain a little better please?

Comment: In my code, which introduced yours,  http://jsbin.com/ciduhegukinu/2/edit - there is only photogallery. All this photos in the js-code - Slider.init(document.body,{ 
     images : [link of picture, link..., link...]. I don't want do it. I want that pictures be in "main-block" (<img src="">...) then they brought in array in javascript, which stay in Slider.init.

Comment: In your code you forgot `document.body` as first argument for Slider.init().

Comment: It is not work. I add document.body See my update code.

Comment: I do not know if i exactly understood what you actually want. However my interpretation: Currently you pass the img-sources static object to your `slider-init()`. You want this to happen automatically. This means: Go through the `main-block`-div container and search for images. Get the src of those images and pass those to your `slider.init()`-function? By the way: I highly recommend you using JQuery. Makes life ways easier.

Comment: It is task. I don't have any way. I shell complete this task in javascript language, but not JQuery. I want to pictures lie in div "main-block". My code is not work.

Comment: Dear Cat, calm down. Your approach to get the pictures from `main-block` is correct, all urls should be in your var `slides`. But the last lines of your **not-working code** should be: `Slider.init(document.body, {images : slides});`. Try it.

Comment: Please, help me. It is not a problem. Problem is in the structure in page. My gallery should be under big page (which width 100%) and right of menu (left block). This table don't work! If I write in body html some code my javascript start don't work.

Comment: Yeah, your html is totally confused. For what you need this table?

Comment: See my post. Where write "I want:". Big picture (up, width: 100%, height: 600px), menu (left width:400px, height: 600 px), photogalery (here all javascript code, right), footer (down width:100%).

Comment: Use to (because it is work)    -    Slider.init(document.body,{ 
        images : [ "http://www.uznayvse.ru/images/stories/uzn_1384119271.jpg",
            "http://i.redigo.ru/4fb0dd2a4e202.jpg",
        ]
          });

Comment: Basically I understand. I will try an answer, it take some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write the whole page for you, so this is surely not a complete answer.
1) Start with the html you find here. It will give your page basically the structure you asked for. When you insert elements for your needs, dont forget to close them properly. 2) Forget the css you have posted, it has not much to do with your html. Write your own css for the elements you have and put it into style-tag in head. 3) Put your script into script-tag at bottom.

I hope this will help you to get the right direction.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #menu {float: left; width: 30%}
        #main-block {float: right; width: 70%}
        #footer {clear: both;}
        /* put your css here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <img src="images/top.gif" width="100%" height="300px">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="menu_foto">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""></a></li><br>
                <li><a href=""></a></li><br>
                <li><a href=""></a></li><br>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-block">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/1.jpg">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/2.jpg"><br>
        <img src="images/fotogalery/3.jpg">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/4.jpg"><br>
        <img src="images/fotogalery/5.jpg">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/6.jpg"><br>
        <img src="images/fotogalery/7.jpg">
        <img src="images/fotogalery/8.jpg"><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p> Put in here what you want to have in footer</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    /* put your javascript here */
</script>
</html>
```